# Валидация объекта

Tags: javascript

У меня есть объект:

```js
{
  messages: [259259, 259258],
  mood: "positive",
  heading: 2,
  tags: [1, 2],
  theme: 236
}
```

Мне нужно перед отправкой данных на сервер проверить, чтобы объект содержал именно эти поля, типа данных как в примере:
`messages` - массив,
`mood` - строка,
`heading` - число,
`tags` - массив,
`theme` - число
и чтобы поля объекта были не пустыми. Простая валидация на пустой объект у меня получается легко, а тут ступор.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  messages: [259259, 259258],
  mood: null,
  heading: 2,
  tags: [1, 2],
  theme: 236
};

function isValid(obj) {
  const props = ['messages', 'mood', 'heading', 'tags', 'theme'];
  for (const prop of props) {
    if (
      typeof obj[prop] !== 'number' && !obj[prop] ||
      Array.isArray(obj[prop]) && obj[prop].length !== 2
    ) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(isValid(obj));
```